# Object doesn't support property or method '.DataLabels'

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone explain to me what's generating the "Object doesn't support property or method" error message? Looking through the debugger, it seems that ".Datalabels" isn't supported. Is it because I'm specifying an object instead of a Chart?

The first subroutine is supposed to determine if I selected one chart or multiple charts. The second subroutine is suppose to apply my formatting to the chart.

```
Sub DetermineSelection()
'Determines what to process (active chat or selected chart)
    Dim obj As Object

    If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
        FormatNASATLXChart ActiveChart
    Else
        For Each obj In Selection
            If TypeName(obj) = "ChartObject" Then
                FormatNASATLXChart obj.Chart
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The second subroutine is suppose to apply my formatting to the chart.

```
Sub FormatNASATLXChart(cht As Chart)
'Format chart with NASA TLX Label (i.e. Mental Workload)
    With cht.SeriesCollection(1)
        .DataLabels = True
        .ShowSeriesName = True
        .ShowValue = False
        .Position = xlLabelPositionInsideBase
    End With

    With cht.SeriesCollection(2)
        .HasDataLabels = True
        .ShowSeriesName = True
        .ShowValue = False
        .Position = xlLabelPositionInsideBase
    End With

    With cht.SeriesCollection(3)
        .HasDataLabels = True
        .ShowSeriesName = True
        .ShowValue = False
        .Position = xlLabelPositionInsideBase
    End With

    With cht.SeriesCollection(4)
        .HasDataLabels = True
        .ShowSeriesName = True
        .ShowValue = False
        .Position = xlLabelPositionInsideBase
    End With

    With cht.SeriesCollection(5)
        .HasDataLabels = True
        .ShowSeriesName = True
        .ShowValue = False
        .Position = xlLabelPositionInsideBase
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your line of:

```
.DataLabels = True
```

to:

```
.HasDataLabels = True
```

Right after the line `With cht.SeriesCollection(1)`

---

You could replace your code, which is repeating 5 times the exact same commands with a `For` loop.

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 5
    With cht.SeriesCollection(i)
        .HasDataLabels = True
        .ShowSeriesName = True
        .ShowValue = False
        .Position = xlLabelPositionInsideBase
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: I figured it was something like that, but I didn't see any reference material that indicated anything was wrong with '.DataLabels'. Now I'm getting the same error message with '.ShowSeriesName'. But according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/datalabels-showseriesname-property-powerpoint) that's valid syntax.